# What number representation is the adjoint representation of the Monster?

Tags: finite-groups, modular-forms

Given this [list of representations of the Monster](https://oeis.org/A001379/list). How far along the list until we get to the adjoint representation that is the same size as the Monster group itself?

(This might be interesting because the modular J-functions coefficients is made up of the size of representations the Monster.)

Comment: You won't: it's a list of degrees of **irreducible** reps, so there's only finitely many of them, all of degree less than the square root of the order of $M$.

Comment: how many out of interest?

Comment: $194{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Ah ok thankyou. So each of the coefficients of the J-function can be written as a 194 dimensional integer vector dot-product with a vector of the irreducible representations?